# Multiple string comparsions

Tags: c#, string, comparison

Is there a nicer way of writing an extensive string comparison?

```
string a = '...'
string b = '...' (etc.)

if (a == "something" && b == "something" && c == "something" && d == "something")
{ do something }
```

I have come across this issue many times and it just looks (for want of a better word) bad.

Comment: Use a programming language that allows you to compare arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var strings = new List<string>{a,b,c,d};

if(strings.All(s=>s == "something")){
}
```